# How to resolve AxiosError "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:XX" in PayPal API integration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios, paypal

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal API into my Node.js application, but I'm encountering the following error when using Axios:

> AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:XX

**Explanation and Troubleshooting:**

The error message indicates that the connection to `127.0.0.1:XX` (localhost, port xx(xx = any number)) is being refused. This suggests a problem with either:

- **PayPal API endpoint:** Possible incorrect configuration or a change on PayPal's side.
- **Local server:** A server might not be running, or firewall rules might be blocking it.

**These are the errors:**

> node:internal/process/promises:279
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^ AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:xx  errored: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:xx
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)

**Code:**

**payment.controllers.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {PAYPAL_API, PAYPAL_API_CLIENT, PAYPAL_API_SECRET} from '../config'

export const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
    const order = {
        intent : 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [
            {
                amount: {
                    currency_code:"USD",
                    value: '2'
                },
                description: "suscription"
            },
        ],
        application_context: {
            brand_name: "pomodoro.app",
            landing_page: "LOGIN",
            user_action: "PAY_NOW",
            return_url: 'http://localhost:4000/capture-order',
            cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4000/cancel-order'
        }
    };

    const response = await axios.post('${PAYPAL_API}/v2/checkout/orders', order, {
        auth: {
            username: PAYPAL_API_CLIENT,
            password: PAYPAL_API_SECRET
        }
    });

    console.log(response)

    res.send('creating order');
}

export const captureOrder = (req, res) => {
    res.send('capture an order')
}

export const cancelOrder = (req, res) => {
    res.send('cancel an order')
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
 
  },
 
}
```

**What I've Tried:**

- I've verified my PayPal API credentials (Client ID and Secret).
- I've tried accessing the endpoints `http://localhost:3000/create-order` and `http://localhost:4000/create-order`, but neither is working.
- I've checked, and there doesn't seem to be a server running on port xx (xx = any number).

**Specific Question:**

How can I debug and fix this connection issue to successfully integrate the PayPal API into my Node.js application?

Comment: First; It's probably not so smart to expose the api keys on Stackoverflow even though its for a sandbox environment. And second; Can you include the `routes/payment.routes` file?

Comment: Hello, I deleted my API keys thanks for warning me and I included routes/payment.routes

Comment: The username & password are still visible in the logs :)

Comment: I think now I deleted all the evidence :) (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining the paypal url as `'${PAYPAL_API}/v2/checkout/orders'`, which will be used exactly as-is and won't actually replace the `PAYPAL_API` variable due to the single quotes. You should use back ticks instead as template literals ([see more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) like this:

```js
axios.post(`${PAYPAL_API}/v2/checkout/orders`, ...
```